# Is it possible to use the result of a query as if it were a collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query, Let's call it query 1:

```
db.getCollection('responses').aggregate([
    { $match:{ "commentId" : ObjectId("60a59174f681ac1b34fd67a1") } },      
    {
      $lookup:{
        from:"users",
        localField:"userId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as:"res"
       } 
    }         
])
```

about the result of this query I want to do another $lookup:

```
db.getCollection('comments').aggregate([
    { $match:{ "postId" : "60a355a4404c1617680c1a19" } },
    {
      $lookup:{
       from:"query 1",
       localField:"_id",
       foreignField: "commentId",
       as:"response"
      } 
   }  
])
```

I would like the result to be the following

```
[
    {
        comment1: {
            content,
            responses: [{
                response1: {
                    content,
                    user: {
                        content,
                    }
                },
                response2: {
                    content,
                    user: {
                        content,
                    }
                },
                response3: {
                    content,
                    user: {
                        content,
                    }
                },

            }]
        },
    },
    {
        comment2: {
            content,
            responses: [{
                response1: {
                    content,
                    user: {
                        content,
                    }
                },
                response2: {
                    content,
                    user: {
                        content,
                    }
                },
                response3: {
                    content,
                    user: {
                        content,
                    }
                },

            }]
        },
    }

]
```

these are the collections

```
        users: { _id, name, username }
        posts: {
    _id,
 userId, //user creator of the post
 text,
}
        comments: {_id,
 postId, //id of the publication where the comments are
 text,
 userId, // user creator of the comment

}
 responses: {
 _id,
 commentid, // comment id where the response is directed
 userId, //id of the publication where the response are
 postId, // //id of the publication where the comments are
}
```

- what I am looking for is that in the json it has:
- list of comments with a given postId, where each one contains:
- the content of the comment,
- a field with the userId data,
- an array with all the responses that contain the commentId field that point to this comment,
- and that in turn each response has the data of the user who sent it

**I already solved it, I leave the solution in case it serves someone in the future**

```
    db.getCollection('comments').aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
         "postId" : "60a355a4404c1617680c1a19",
        }
    },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "responses",
    "let": { "comId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$commentId", "$$comId"] }}},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "users",
        "let": { "usId": "$userId" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$usId"] }}}
        ],
        "as": "responses"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "users"
  }},
```

Comment: Yes, just keep adding stages.

Comment: Too bad I don't know how to use the result of a query as if it were a collection

Comment: I would like to save the result in a variable, for example, var res find (query); and then use that "res" to query, example, res.find ()

Comment: Can you post sample data of all collection that you want to join

Comment: there clarify a little more

Comment: I already solved it, I leave the solution in case it serves someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

**I already solved it, I leave the solution in case it serves someone in the future**

```
   db.getCollection('comments').aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
         "postId" : "60a355a4404c1617680c1a19",
        }
    },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "responses",
    "let": { "comId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$commentId", "$$comId"] }}},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "users",
        "let": { "usId": "$userId" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$usId"] }}}
        ],
        "as": "user"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "responses"
  }},
 
])
```